# Latex pop ups an error " misplaced \noalign. \thead->noalign" for a table in document class {cas-sc}. Help needed

Tags: tables, errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}%[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Day ahead accuracy assessment of electricity demand forecasting on US utility GEFCOM-2012}
\label{tab:Day_ahead_Accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Hours &
 \multicolumn{12}{c}{US utility GEFCOM-2012} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-17}
 &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ANN} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{LSTM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{CRBM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{FCDBN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} \cmidrule(l){14-15} \cmidrule(l){16-17}
    & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}}& {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} \\
\midrule
01 & 4.81 & 30.1 & 0.325 & 3.35 & 25.3 & 0.500 & 1.08 & 20.5 & 0.725 & 0.54 & 12.5 & 0.930 \\
02 & 4.84 & 28.4 & 0.625 & 2.80 & 28.9 & 0.590 & 1.11 & 18.9 & 0.756 & 0.63 & 11.2 & 0.990 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where does `\thead` come from? Without the line with all the `\thead` the only error is `Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`.

Comment: @TVL the undefined command is `\bibsep ` (not `\begin{document}`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I incorporated your response. Now it pop ups the error like this misplaced \noalign recently read noalign

Comment: actually `\thead` has to be the first thing in the row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I put it first in the row. However, the same error presisits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. The previous error is resolved. However, now I am facing the error! !missing \endgroup inserted. Help needed Please.

Comment: the code as in my answer generates no error. If you have different code making a different error feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first error is that the length `\bibsep` is not defined (but that appears to be an issue in the class, it is set without defining it)

then you use a command `\thead` the error message shows that it uses `\noalign` so like `\hline` it can only be used between rows not in each cell. I guessed a definition and changed to a new `\theadb` command here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{flafter}

\newlength\bibsep % ??

\newcommand\theadb[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}%[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Day ahead accuracy assessment of electricity demand forecasting on US utility GEFCOM-2012}
\label{tab:Day_ahead_Accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Hours &
 \multicolumn{12}{c}{US utility GEFCOM-2012} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-17}
 &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ANN} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{LSTM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{CRBM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{FCDBN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} \cmidrule(l){14-15} \cmidrule(l){16-17}
    &\theadb{MAPE} & \theadb{RMSE} & \theadb{r} & \theadb{MAPE} & \theadb{RMSE} & \theadb{r}& \theadb{MAPE} & \theadb{RMSE} & \theadb{r} & \theadb{MAPE} & \theadb{RMSE} & \theadb{r} \\
\midrule
01 & 4.81 & 30.1 & 0.325 & 3.35 & 25.3 & 0.500 & 1.08 & 20.5 & 0.725 & 0.54 & 12.5 & 0.930 \\
02 & 4.84 & 28.4 & 0.625 & 2.80 & 28.9 & 0.590 & 1.11 & 18.9 & 0.756 & 0.63 & 11.2 & 0.990 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks now it works perfectly.