# Latex pop ups error "!Missing \endgroup inserted for a table in document class Elsevier {cas-sc}. How can I resolve this problem?

Tags: tables, els-cas

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{flafter}

\newlength\bibsep % ??

\newcommand\theadb[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}%[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{The 95\% prediction interval nominal.}
\label{tab:CI}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{16}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Hours &
 \multicolumn{8}{c}{US utility GEFCOM-2012} &
 \multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{ISO-NE control area} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-9} \cmidrule(l){10-17}
 &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ANN} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{LSTM} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{CRBM} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCDBN} &
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{ANN} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{LSTM} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{CRBM} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{FCDBN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} \cmidrule(l){14-15} \cmidrule(l){16-17}
    & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} & \theadb{Lower\\ bound} & \theadb{Upper\\ bound} \\
\midrule
 01&4.4&6.0 &3.2  &3.9  &3.0  &3.9  &1.9  &2.5 &4.5&6.4 &3.1  &3.7  &3.1 &3.9  &1.7  &2.4 \\
 02&4.6&6.1 &4.5  &5.1  &4.1  &4.5  &1.6  &1.9 &4.3&6.5 &4.3  &5.2  &4.3  &4.5  &1.5  &1.8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\theadb` is basically defined as `\multicolumn{1}{c}`. Since you can't use `\\ ` to add a linebreak inside of a `c` type column, you can't use `\\ ` to get a linebreak inside of `\theadb`.

Comment: From the code in [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583788/134144) on a similar topic, I guess, you actually used the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package, which in turn seems to cause issues when used in combination with `cas-sc`, aparently due to `\cs_gset_eq:NN \thead  \toprule 
\cs_gset_eq:NN \endthead  \midrule ` inside of `cas-common.sty` which in turn is loaded by `cas-sc`.

Comment: I have removed the `longtable` `tabularx` `tabulary` `xtable` tags, since the code in your question uses neither of these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested

```
 \newcommand\theadb[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
```

in a previous answer, which fitted the example you gave but `c` columns are single line.

here you use a multi-line entry so use something like

```
\newcommand\theadb[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1\end{tabular}}}
```

so the cell is a nested tabular and `\\`  will work as you intend.

Comment: I tried your suggested commands, however, it does not work. Please facilitate if possible.

Comment: @GhulamHafeez If you take the document in your question and replace the line in my first code block by the two lines in the second code block then it runs without error.

Comment: @DavidCarlies. Ok, I will check and let you know.

Comment: @DavidCarlies. Many thanks. I followed your recommendations in the second block code. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: that is what the answer said to do:-) But glad you got it working.