# Latex pop up error Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit@multispan for Table in Elsevier cas-sc template

Tags: tables, tabularx, xtable, els-cas, mwe

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{{Week ahead forecasted load accuracy assessment of the proposed and existing forecasting frameworks in terms of \emph{r} on case study I.}}
\label{tab:R_WF_US}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed and existing frameworks} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Days}
        & {\thead{ANN \\ \emph{r}}}
            & {\thead{LSTM \\ \emph{r}}}
                & {\thead{CRBM \\ \emph{r}}}
                     & {\thead{FCRBM \\ \emph{r}}}\\

\midrule
    Sunday & 0.250 & 0.520 & 0.795 & 0.815 \\
    Monday & 0.321 & 0.515 & 0.778 & 0.912 \\
    Tuesday & 0.755 & 0.656 & 0.795 & 0.845 \\
    Wednesday & 0.250 & 0.566 & 0.615 & 0.998 \\
    Thursday & 0.445 & 0.465 & 0.809 & 0.877 \\
    Friday & 0.335 & 0.536 & 0.700 & 0.899 \\
    Saturday & 0.438 & 0.486 & 0.697 & 0.919 \\
    \midrule
Avg.& 0.400 & 0.534 & 0.751 & 0.895\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message you quote, but get a different one due to the missing `\usepackage{natbib}`. If I add this line to the MWE, I get a code, that compiles without error messages.

Comment: The error message you quote contains `\theadb{LSTM MAPE (\%)}` which is not present in your MWE. So I assume, the error is caused by a different table in your document. Also, this was probably just a typo as you maybe wanted to use `\thead` as opposed to `\theadb`?

Comment: @leandriis. I added \usepackage{natbib}. Then it generates an error like Misplaced \noalign. \thead -->\noalign. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you still get the error message if you take the MWE from your question and add `\usepackage{natbib}` to it or does your comment refer to your actual document? In the latter case, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error message you get.

Comment: @leandriis. Still error persists...

Comment: Do you get the error message if you use the exact same code you posted here or if you use a different and larger document?

Comment: Could it be possible that `\theadb` actually is not a typo, but a user defined command? If you use the definition of `\theadb` provided by David Carlisle [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583845/134144), try to remove the set of `{}` around \theadb and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that `\thead` cannot be used in `S` column headers, because it should be braced, but it uses some `\noalign` tricks that can't work if it is braced. The culprit seems to be the particular document class.

A workaround, with some fixes to the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mythead}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[pos=!htbp]
\centering

\caption{{Week ahead forecasted load accuracy assessment of
  the proposed and existing forecasting frameworks in terms
  of \textit{r} on case study I.}}
\label{tab:R_WF_US}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
  table-format=1.2,
  detect-all,
}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} @{}}
\toprule
Days & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\makebox[0pt]{Proposed and existing frameworks}} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
  & \mythead{ANN \\ \textit{r}}
  & \mythead{LSTM \\ \textit{r}}
  & \mythead{CRBM \\ \textit{r}}
  & \mythead{FCRBM \\ \textit{r}}\\

\midrule
    Sunday & 0.250 & 0.520 & 0.795 & 0.815 \\
    Monday & 0.321 & 0.515 & 0.778 & 0.912 \\
    Tuesday & 0.755 & 0.656 & 0.795 & 0.845 \\
    Wednesday & 0.250 & 0.566 & 0.615 & 0.998 \\
    Thursday & 0.445 & 0.465 & 0.809 & 0.877 \\
    Friday & 0.335 & 0.536 & 0.700 & 0.899 \\
    Saturday & 0.438 & 0.486 & 0.697 & 0.919 \\
    \midrule
Avg.& 0.400 & 0.534 & 0.751 & 0.895\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that the position specifiers have to be used as values for the key `pos`.

I also set the long header in a box of width zero, because its natural width is larger than the natural width of the spanned columns, so you'd get an excess width in the last column.

Note also `detect-all` in order to typeset the figures in the overall style of tables. Instead of `\emph{r}` (I guess you want to emulate math mode), use `\textit` because you *do* want italics, not emphasis.

[image]

Comment: Would you explain a bit more about "I'm afraid that \thead cannot be used in S column headers, because it should be braced, but it uses some \noalign tricks that can't work if it is braced.". I don't remember encountering an issue when using `\thead` inside of `S` columns, provided, the `\thead` command is inside a set of `{}`. In fact, `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{makecell,siunitx} \begin{document} \begin{tabular}{|l|*{2}{S[table-format=1]|}} \thead{text} & {\thead[l]{a\\ text}} & {\thead{a\\ bb}}\\ text & 1 & 2\\ \end{tabular} \end{document}` seems to produce the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis I guess there is some problem with the particular class.

Comment: If I replace `article` with `cas-sc` and add the `natbib` package to the MWE in my previous comment, I still get the expected output and no error message.

Comment: @leandriis I get the `Misplaced \noalign` error (TeX Live 2021 just updated).

Comment: I also just updated my packages and still can not reproduce the `Misplaced \noalign` error. Admittedly, I use MiKTeX, so there might still be a version difference.