# CAS class does not generate PDF. Gives error undefine control sequence?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, elsarticle, els-cas

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[options]{natbib}
%\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithm2e} % <============================================
\usepackage{pseudocode} % <=============================================
\usepackage{blindtext}% <=============================================
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
%\doublespacing
%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}


\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}


\title [mode = title]{energy optimization}

\author[1]{ Ahmad }[]
\affiliation[1]{organization={Electrical Engineering Department,  Najran University},
    city={Najran},
    % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
    postcode={11001},
    % state={},
    country={Saudi Arabia}}
\begin{abstract}
he FCDBN based framework reduces average execution time to 188 seconds while benchmark models like CRBM reduce to 195 seconds, ANN to 210 seconds, and LSTM to 220 seconds. Results validate that the proposed FCDBN based forecasting framework's performance is outstanding compared to benchmark frameworks.
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
Deep belief network \sep
electricity demand forecasting \sep
factored conditional deep belief network \sep
neural network \sep
deep neural network \sep
smart grid\sep
\end{keywords}

\section*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\begin{IEEEdescription}[\IEEEusemathlabelsep\IEEEsetlabelwidth{$V_1,V_2,V_3$}]
\item[] \textbf{ABBREVIATIONS}
\item[ANN]  Artificial neural network
\item[ARMA] Autoregressive moving average
\section{Introduction}\label{Introduction}
\doublespacing
Ali baba

\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Day ahead accuracy assessment of electricity demand forecasting on US utility GEFCOM-2012}
\label{tab:Day_ahead_Accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Hours &
 \multicolumn{12}{c}{US utility GEFCOM-2012} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-17}
 &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ANN} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{LSTM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{CRBM} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{FCDBN} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13} %\cmidrule(l){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} \cmidrule(l){14-15} \cmidrule(l){16-17}
    & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}}& {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} & {\thead{MAPE}} & {\thead{RMSE}} & {\thead{r}} \\
\midrule
01 & 4.81 & 30.1 & 0.325 & 3.35 & 25.3 & 0.500 & 1.08 & 20.5 & 0.725 & 0.54 & 12.5 & 0.930 \\
02 & 4.84 & 28.4 & 0.625 & 2.80 & 28.9 & 0.590 & 1.11 & 18.9 & 0.756 & 0.63 & 11.2 & 0.990 \\
03 & 3.80 & 30.6 & 0.551 & 3.27 & 23.3 & 0.585 & 1.10 & 17.3 & 0.805 & 0.45 & 9.12 & 0.976 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem may be from: `[\IEEEusemathlabelsep\IEEEsetlabelwidth{$V_1,V_2,V_3$}]`

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Environment IEEEdescription undefined.`

Comment: I removed this issue "!LaTeX Error: Environment IEEEdescription undefined." However, still it does not generate PDF. Please help. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @M.Logic Yes, i agree. Comment "[\IEEEusemathlabelsep\IEEEsetlabelwidth{$V_1,V_2,V_3$}]" this. But still PDF does not generate. Please help. Thanks

Comment: edit the example in the question so it shows the problem you want to ask about. Do you _really_ use all those packages?? why is `blindtext` loaded? twice!! why do you have `\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}` (which more or less makes floating figures impossible)?

Comment: latex will never fail to make  pdf without giving an error message. Show the exact error copied from the log in a code block in the question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I resolved some issues in the code and edited the code in question. However, Still i get this error "\multispan ->\omit  \@multispan". Picture of error is attached. Please resolve the issue.

Comment: @M. Logic. I resolved some issues in the code and edited the code in question. However, Still i get this error "\multispan ->\omit \@multispan". Picture of error is attached. Please resolve the issue.

Comment: Please help in resolving the issue. I tried a lot but unable to resolve this issue...

Comment: See also: [Latex pop ups an error " misplaced \noalign. \thead->noalign" for a table in document class {cas-sc}. Help needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583788/134144)